# Slim Backlight Keyboard?

Tags: keyboards

I would like something like this keyboard except where the quality is assured to work for a long while:
http://a.co/d/i1uzVA1

---

**Requirements:**

*Needs to be slim (like Surface/Mac desktop keyboard)
*Needs to be backlit and allow for white color light
*Needs to be wireless (i.e. contains USB dongle)
*Manufacturing reliability must be verified and must have reputation for quality products
*Needs to be full desktop keyboard (i.e. contains numpad section)
*Keyboard must be for English-native speakers/typists
*Space bar must be big enough to stretch from the 'X' key to the '.' key

---

**Preferred but not required:**

*Color variation for keyboard itself
*Individual keys spaced out symmetrically and big enough
*Keyboard is **not** mechanical

---

**Irrelevant**:

*Price
*Battery-type (e.g. AA, AAA)
*Warranty
*Product dimensions
*Function keys

---

I've looked on Amazon and Newegg. I haven't had much luck with the type of keyboard I'm looking for. The only keyboard that has come close is the one I've linked to above. I was going to invest in it until I read the reviews for it. It appears that the quality control for it are sub-standard and so I would like an identical keyboard but from someone who I can trust to make a decent keyboard.

TIA